# Is there a character that sorts before the newline character, for managing sort order in 'ls'?

Tags: ls, filenames, unicode, ascii

I'm developing some file naming guidelines, and I'm trying to find a way to allow a draft document to list before a final revision.

Example:
Currently my naming convention looks like this:

```
contract_foo_v1
contract_foo_v1~draft1
contract_foo_v1~draft2
contract_foo_v2
contract_foo_v2~draft1
```

The problem is that v1~draft should list *before* v1 (the final revision). 
Is there a character I can use that would list as follows:

```
contract_foo_v1?draft1
contract_foo_v1?draft2
contract_foo_v1
contract_foo_v2?draft1
contract_foo_v2
```

I also understand that there may be locale and program differences, so I'm after recommendations for a character that would work as requested in most cases (or as many cases as possible) - Thanks for any help

Comment: Why not use a revision control system such as Git, CVS or even RCS?

Comment: Call the final version `contract_foo_v1-final` and the drafts `contract_foo_v1-draftN`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I do use a vcs (git) for my stuff, but this is a naming guideline for the staff in the company who are not that technically inclined. I'm trying to avoid using the final keyword, to mitigate the risk of contract_somesupplier_v01-final-final-lastone-03.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ls` sorts the list of files based on their name which in your case doesn't contain newline characters. Even `sort` sorts on the *contents* of the lines which don't include the newline character, so here it's not about finding a character that sorts *before newline*, but one that sorts *before nothing* and you won't find one.

Now, GNU `ls -v` (for version-sort) does happen to sort that list of files in the order you want:

```
$ ls -v1
contract_foo_v1~draft1
contract_foo_v1~draft2
contract_foo_v1
contract_foo_v2~draft1
contract_foo_v2
contract_foo_v10
```

Without `-v`, since `ls` does a lexical sort, `v10` would also sort before `v2`.

With GNU `sort`, you can also use `sort -V` on the output of `ls` (assuming your file names don't contain newline characters):

```
$ ls | sort -V
contract_foo_v1~draft1
contract_foo_v1~draft2
contract_foo_v1
contract_foo_v2~draft1
contract_foo_v2
contract_foo_v10
```

POSIXly, you could do:

```
$ ls | sort -t'~' -k1.15,1n -k2,2.1r -k2n
contract_foo_v1~draft1
contract_foo_v1~draft2
contract_foo_v1
contract_foo_v2~draft1
contract_foo_v2
contract_foo_v10
```

But that assumes the part before the version is always 14 characters long.

With the `zsh`, shell, you could define a glob sort order like:

```
drafts_first() {
  [[ $REPLY = *'~draft'* ]] || REPLY="$REPLY~release"
}
printf '%s\n' *(no+drafts_first)
```

You could also choose to name your files like `contract_foo_v001_draft01` and `contract_foo_v001_release` (or `contract_foo_v001_final` as suggested by @Kusalananda; any word that sorts after `draft`), assuming you never have more than 999 versions per document and 99 drafts per version, then they would sort in the right order with `ls` alone or any tool that lists files in lexical order.

See also `ls -rt` to sort files by modification time (newest last), or the `Om` glob qualifier of `zsh`.

Now, if you add an extension (like `.pdf`) to those file names, then that becomes a whole different story:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ls -1
contract_foo_v10.pdf
contract_foo_v1~draft1.pdf
contract_foo_v1~draft2.pdf
contract_foo_v1.pdf
contract_foo_v2~draft1.pdf
contract_foo_v2.pdf
$ LC_ALL=C ls -1
contract_foo_v1.pdf
contract_foo_v10.pdf
contract_foo_v1~draft1.pdf
contract_foo_v1~draft2.pdf
contract_foo_v2.pdf
contract_foo_v2~draft1.pdf
```

In my `en_US.UTF-8` locale, both `~` and `.` are ignored in the first comparison pass, so `v10` comes before `v1~d` because `0` sorts before `d`, and `v1~draft` comes before `v1.pdf` because `draft` sorts before `pdf` (that would be different with a `.docx` extension).

In the C locale, where there's only one pass and the sorting is based on byte value, `.`, `0` and `~` sort in that order. `~` is the printable character with highest value in ASCII, so it would be the poorest choice there. There are quite a few that come before `.` like `#`, `-`, `%`, all of them *ignored* in the first pass above in locales that follow iso14651_t1.

So if we fix the v2 vs v10 by using 0-padding and use `-` instead of `~`, with `.pdf` extensions we get the order we want both in *human* locales and in `C`/`C.UTF-8` locales where the order is based on code point:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ls -1
contract_foo_v01-draft1.pdf
contract_foo_v01-draft2.pdf
contract_foo_v01.pdf
contract_foo_v02-draft1.pdf
contract_foo_v02.pdf
contract_foo_v10.pdf
$ LC_ALL=C ls -1
contract_foo_v01-draft1.pdf
contract_foo_v01-draft2.pdf
contract_foo_v01.pdf
contract_foo_v02-draft1.pdf
contract_foo_v02.pdf
contract_foo_v10.pdf
```

Comment: Not the answer that I was hoping for, but "no character sorts before nothing" is the reality I have to deal with. I was really hoping to avoid using the final keyword for the same reasons I mentioned in the comment above but I may have to (or at least use something alphabetical that makes sense internally) - thanks for the detailed reply on the ls usage, that is really handy to know (and I think I will be adjusting my aliases going forward!)

Comment: @cleary, see edit if those files have a `.pdf` extension as your comment suggests. Again, bear in mind that `v10` sorts before `v2` lexically. The usual way around that is to use 0-padding.

Comment: that's very interesting ... I used PDF only as a generic file format for the purposes of the post. But, the vast majority of our internal documents are actually in opendocument format, which would also work well in this example (.odt, .ods, .odX). Thanks for the follow up, appreciate it!